# How to return field which has that value from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document like this

```
{
    "field_1": ["val_1", "val_2"],
    "field_2": ["val_21", "val_14"],
    "field_3": ["val_6", "val_9"]
}
```

If I search for "val_1", I want to get "field_1" and if I search for "val_9" I want to get "field_3" from elasticsearch response. So to know which field the value matched in.

How can i do that in elasticsearch.

I am using:

```
Version: 2.3.2, Build: b9e4a6a/2016-04-21T16:03:47Z, JVM: 1.8.0_91
```

Comment: What do you mean by "getting field_n"?

Comment: Andrei Stefan I mean i would somehow like to know from the response that the value was matched in which particular field.

Comment: The only thing you can use is [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html). I'll post an answer to demonstrate with your data and an assumed (default) mapping.

Answer (score 0):

```
POST /www/test/1
{"field_1":["val_1","val_2"],"field_2":["val_21","val_14"],"field_3":["val_6","val_9"]}

GET /www/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "val_1",
      "fields": ["field_*"]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "field_*":{}
    }
  }
}
```

And for this data and query, this would be the output:

```
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "www",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.058849156,
        "_source": {
           "field_1": [
              "val_1",
              "val_2"
           ],
           "field_2": [
              "val_21",
              "val_14"
           ],
           "field_3": [
              "val_6",
              "val_9"
           ]
        },
        "highlight": {
           "field_1": [
              "<em>val_1</em>"
           ]
        }
     }
  ]
```

So, for highlighting you get a separate section - `highlight` - where, depending on the queries you get the highlighted *value* in a certain field.